# MySQL JOIN: Select a row if a bool column is 1, otherwise select the first row

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables: `products(id)` and `product_images(id, parent_id, src, is_default)`

Each product has `n` images.

I want to get all products and **one** image for each of them.

If the column `is_default` is 1(`BOOL`), then get that image, otherwise get the first one.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT 
   main.*,
   images.id image_id, images.src image_src
FROM products main 
   LEFT JOIN product_images images ON main.id = images.parent_id AND images.is_default = 1
GROUP BY main.id
ORDER BY main.id DESC
```

Obviously the `JOIN` condition is not right and I can't figure it out.

Hope you can help,

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "Join condition is not right"? please add the problem you are getting

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.

Are you asking to return the default image if such an image exists, otherwise return the first image?

How do you identify the first image?

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr The first image is basically the first inserted, so with the lowest ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GROUP_CONCAT.

This gets all the image details for each main ordered by is_default descending, and then by id. So if there are no records with is_default set to 1 then it will get the first image first. Then uses SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the first details.

Note that if images.src can contain a comma you might want to use a different delimiter.

```
SELECT 
   main.*,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(images.id ORDER BY images.is_default DESC, images.id), ',', 1) AS image_id, 
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(images.src ORDER BY images.is_default DESC, images.id), ',', 1) AS image_src
FROM products main 
LEFT JOIN product_images images ON main.id = images.parent_id 
GROUP BY main.id
ORDER BY main.id DESC
```

Comment: For some reason this only works when there is at least one is_default column with the value 1, when they are all 0 null is returned.

Comment: Doh, typo. Fixed now I think.

Comment: Indeed it works perfectly now, and it's much cleaner. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the first image is the one with the lowest ID, I would start with this query:

```
SELECT
  parent_id,
  COALESCE(
    MIN(CASE WHEN is_default=1 THEN ID END),
    MIN(id)
  ) AS image_id
FROM product_images
GROUP BY parent_id
```

this will return the image where is_default = 1, if there's no default MIN(case when...) will be null and then COALESCE will select just MIN(id). Then you can join your query with the previous subquery:

```
SELECT main.*, images.id image_id, images.src image_src
FROM
  products main LEFT JOIN JOIN (
    SELECT
      parent_id,
      COALESCE(
        MIN(CASE WHEN is_default=1 THEN ID END),
        MIN(id)
      ) AS min_image_id
    FROM product_images
    GROUP BY parent_id
  ) fi ON fi.parent_id = main.id
  LEFT JOIN product_images images
  ON images.id = fi.min_image_id
```

Comment: This works as expected in all cases, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the single image information in a subquery:

```
SELECT main.*, 
 (SELECT images.id 
  FROM product_images image 
  WHERE main.id = images.parent_id 
  AND images.is_default = 1
  ORDER BY images.id
 ) image_id,
 (SELECT images.src 
  FROM product_images image 
  WHERE main.id = images.parent_id 
  AND images.is_default = 1
  ORDER BY images.id
 ) image_src
FROM products main
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a sub-query. I think this is the simplest solution.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT main.*, images.id image_id, images.src image_src
    FROM products as main
    LEFT JOIN product_images as images ON main.id = images.parent_id
    ORDER BY images.is_default DESC
) as t
GROUP BY t.id
```

This does what you want, but orders by the images.is_default desc, so that if the is_default is 1, then this will show at the top. The outer query `GROUP BY` will force the one with the is_default to be selected if `is_default` is set.

Comment: you are grouping by t.id but selecting *, even if the inner query is ordered there are no guarantees that the outer query will return the correct value, the result is considered to be undeterminate

Comment: @fthiella - Many thanks. I've heard that before - but have seen no evidence of mysql working unexpectedly. Can you give me an example of where this fails or a resource showing this failing?

Comment: I would not use an undocumented feature on a live environment, here's an example where it fails https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/ (it's mariadb but it might happen on mysql as well)